# How to get Postgres to "give up" filtering?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that tries to (very naïvely) implement fuzzy searching for country names:

```
WITH matching_countries AS (
  SELECT * FROM directory.country WHERE id = $1
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM directory.country 
  WHERE
    alpha2 = $2 OR
    alpha3 = $2 OR
    name = $2 OR
    canonical_name = $2 OR
    name LIKE $3 OR
    canonical_name LIKE $3
  UNION
  SELECT country.* FROM directory.country country
  LEFT JOIN directory.country_alias cAlias
    ON cAlias.country_id = country.id
  WHERE
    cAlias.name = $2 OR
    cAlias.name LIKE $3
)
SELECT * FROM matching_countries
ORDER BY LENGTH(name) ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Ideally this query should just "give up" scanning tables once an accurate match has been found, as every line you go down we sacrifice accuracy to hopefully make a fuzzy match. I thought `LIMIT 1` would do this, but it seems to be picking up blatant false-positives from the `LIKE` filters.

How can I make it "give up"/early-return on a match? I am optimizing this as I had implemented it as multiple individual queries from application-code but it was quite a bit slow to do it that way instead of `UNION`-ing all queries.

Comment: Can you please post the EXPLAIN? I can't imagine this would be slow, given there are a few hundred countries in the world...

Comment: The `ORDER BY` means all rows have to be ordered before you do LIMIT 1.

Comment: You could add a `limit 1` to each of the (inner) UNION queries then the outer query needs to only sort at most three rows

Comment: @NevilleKuyt We generated quite a bit of aliases for the countries so we'd rather avoid hitting the aliases table if possible.

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` makes no sense, and can be reduced to an `EXISTS ()`

Answer (score 2):

First, I would use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` to avoid additional sorting.

If you want to rank the results, use something like

```
WITH matching_countries AS (
    SELECT *,
           1 AS match_level
    FROM directory.country
    WHERE /* first condition */
  UNION ALL
    SELECT *,
           2 AS match_level
    FROM directory.country 
    WHERE /* second condition */
  UNION
    ...
)
SELECT *
FROM matching_countries
ORDER BY match_level, length(name)
LIMIT 1;
```

This will still execute all the `UNION ALL` branches, but it will return a match from the first subquery that returned a result.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work:

---

```
SELECT version();

CREATE TABLE country
        ( id integer not null primary key
        , name text
        , canonical_name text
        );
INSERT INTO country(id, name, canonical_name) VALUES
 ( 1, 'United Kingdom', 'UK' )
, ( 2, 'Deutchland', 'DE' )
, ( 3, 'France', 'FR' )
, ( 4, 'Nederland', 'NL' )
        ;

CREATE TABLE country_alias
        ( id SERIAL not null primary key
        , country_id integer not null REFERENCES country(id)
        , name text
        );
INSERT INTO country_alias(country_id, name) VALUES
 ( 1, 'Britain' )
, ( 1, 'Great Britain' )
, ( 2, 'Germany')
, ( 3, 'Marianne')
, ( 3, 'Ohlala')
, ( 4, 'Holland' )
, ( 4, 'Kaaskoppen' )
        ;

----------

prepare onion(integer, text, text) AS
WITH one AS (
  SELECT 'one' AS tag, * FROM country
  WHERE id = $1
  )
, two AS (
        SELECT 'two' AS tag, * FROM country
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM one)
        AND ( name = $2
           OR name ILIKE $3
           OR canonical_name = $2
           OR canonical_name ILIKE $3
           )
        )
, three AS (
        SELECT 'three' AS tag, *
        FROM country co
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM two)
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM country_alias ca
        WHERE ca.country_id = co.id
        AND ( ca.name = $2 OR ca.name ILIKE $3)
        )
)
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT * FROM one
        UNION ALL SELECT * FROM two
        UNION ALL SELECT * FROM three
        ) six
-- ORDER BY LENGTH(name) ASC
LIMIT 1
        ;

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE onion(1,'Huge Britain', 'Uk');
EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE onion(6,'Huge Britain', 'U%');

EXECUTE onion(9,'Ned', 'kaas%');
EXPLAIN ANALYZE EXECUTE onion(11,'Huge Britain', 'U%');
```

---

Result:

---

```
 PostgreSQL 11.6 on armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf, compiled by gcc (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0, 32-bit
(1 row)

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 4
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 7
PREPARE
                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=90.37..90.39 rows=1 width=100) (actual time=0.163..0.165 rows=1 loops=1)
   CTE one
     ->  Index Scan using country_pkey on country  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=100) (actual time=0.054..0.055 rows=0 loops=1)
           Index Cond: (id = 6)
   CTE two
     ->  Result  (cost=0.02..27.02 rows=850 width=100) (actual time=0.083..0.084 rows=1 loops=1)
           One-Time Filter: (NOT $1)
           InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
             ->  CTE Scan on one one_1  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
           ->  Seq Scan on country country_1  (cost=0.00..27.00 rows=850 width=68) (actual time=0.069..0.070 rows=1 loops=1)
                 Filter: ((name = 'Huge Britain'::text) OR (name ~~* 'U%'::text) OR (canonical_name = 'Huge Britain'::text) OR (canonical_name ~~* 'U%'::text))
   CTE three
     ->  Result  (cost=35.52..60.98 rows=425 width=100) (never executed)
           One-Time Filter: (NOT $3)
           InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
             ->  CTE Scan on two two_1  (cost=0.00..17.00 rows=850 width=0) (never executed)
           ->  Hash Join  (cost=35.50..60.96 rows=425 width=68) (never executed)
                 Hash Cond: (co.id = ca.country_id)
                 ->  Seq Scan on country co  (cost=0.00..18.50 rows=850 width=68) (never executed)
                 ->  Hash  (cost=33.00..33.00 rows=200 width=4) (never executed)
                       ->  HashAggregate  (cost=31.00..33.00 rows=200 width=4) (never executed)
                             Group Key: ca.country_id
                             ->  Seq Scan on country_alias ca  (cost=0.00..28.00 rows=1200 width=4) (never executed)
                                   Filter: ((name = 'Huge Britain'::text) OR (name ~~* 'U%'::text))
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..31.90 rows=1276 width=100) (actual time=0.158..0.159 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  CTE Scan on one  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=100) (actual time=0.060..0.061 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  CTE Scan on two  (cost=0.00..17.00 rows=850 width=100) (actual time=0.092..0.093 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  CTE Scan on three  (cost=0.00..8.50 rows=425 width=100) (never executed)
 Planning Time: 2.560 ms
 Execution Time: 1.169 ms
(30 rows)

  tag  | id |   name    | canonical_name 
-------+----+-----------+----------------
 three |  4 | Nederland | NL
(1 row)
```

---

Most important detail of ths query plan are the last few lines:

```
->  CTE Scan on one  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=100)
(actual time=0.060..0.061 rows=0 loops=1)
->  CTE Scan on two  (cost=0.00..17.00 rows=850 width=100)
(actual time=0.092..0.093 rows=1 loops=1)
->  CTE Scan on three  (cost=0.00..8.50 rows=425 width=100)
(never executed)
```

So, `one` does not yield any rows, causing `two` to be used, which does results in some rows, such that `three` does not need to be evaluated at all. (in this case the estimates are off, because the freshly created tables have no valid statistics)